# Как в проект добавить Svg файл

Tags: java, android

B приложении имеется `ImageView` и в нем `.png` файл надо заменить на `svg`.

Как добавить `svg` и вставить в `ImageView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Android studio в дереве проекта нажми правую кнопку мыши, далее New > Vector asset. В открывшемся окне выбери "Local file (SVG, PSD)". Таким образом, добавишь новый ресурс-картинку в drawable. Далее удали старую картинку, а новую назови ее именем.